# How to use ref, or watch, or similar functionalities in Vue Composition API

Tags: vue.js

I want to know how can I use ref or watch in setup() area of Vue 3 when importing vue through a CDN.

Here's the code:

```
<div id="app">

    {{ counter }}

  </div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
```

```
const app = Vue.createApp({
  props: {
    name: String
  },
  setup(){
    const capacity = ref(3)
  },
  data(){
    return {
      counter: 43
    }
  },
})
```

This throws an error

> ref is not defined

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To import ref try:

```js
const { createApp, ref, computed, watch } = Vue;
```

You need to return variables from `setup` as object like this

```js
const app = createApp({
  props: {
    name: String
  },
  setup(){
    const capacity = ref(3)
    return { capacity };
  },
  /* data(){  // NO NEED
    return {
      counter: 43
    }
  }, */
})
```

Comment: Thank you for reminding the return issue but the error is about ref that the browser doesn't access to it and throws error "ref is not defined"

If we use build systems we import { ref } from 'vue' but I want to know how can i access to ref or watch in Composition API when accessing Vue through a CDN

Comment: Thank you so much for the time and the answer. It felt like a beautiful Indian song. Thank you